# CSS grid height isn't working as I expected, where did I mess up?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm currently learning about CSS grids, and am tasked with making this card by breaking it down to grids. Attached is a picture of the grids I want to make.

There's actually a bigger grid (profile-grid in the css) where all these cards are lined up, and this bigger grid has a height of 255px. I want to make the cards and the grids inside the card to follow this 255px, and I managed to get the height of the card itself correct, but not the for the inner grid. The inner grid itself is comprised of 2 rows, where the first row is a picture and has a height of 150px, and the second row is set to 1fr, but I couldn't get the inner grids to be 255px in height. Is there any part where I messed up?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Eh6.png

jsFiddle link as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/40tnwd1o/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: roboto;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.profile-card {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 255px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.301);
}

.profile-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 1fr;
}

.social-ava {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: opacity 0.15s;
}

.social-ava:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.social-text {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.social-name {
  margin-top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s;
}

.social-name:hover {
  color: rgb(52, 98, 167);
}

.mutual-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
  margin-top: 6px;
  align-items: center;
}

.mutual-pic {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mutual-friend {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mutual-friend:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.social-add {
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(25, 118, 240);
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.social-add:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!-- profile card start -->
<div class="profile-card">

  <!-- profile grid start -->
  <div class="profile-grid">

    <!-- row 1: picture start -->
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="social-ava"></div>
      <!-- placeholder for profile picture -->
    </div>
    <!-- row 1: picture end -->

    <!-- row 2: info start -->
    <div class="social-text">
      <p class="social-name"><strong>Name</strong></p>

      <div class="mutual-grid">
        <!-- grid for mutual friends info start -->
        <div class="mutual-pic"></div>
        <!-- placeholder for mutual's profile picture -->
        <p class="mutual-friend">2 mutual friends</p>
      </div>
      <!-- grid for mutual friends info end -->

      <button class="social-add">Add Friend</button>
    </div>
    <!-- row 2: info end -->

  </div>
  <!-- profile grid end -->

</div>
<!-- profile card end -->
```

Comment: The card is 255px in height, yes. You may need to make every card have `justify-self:stretch` if the same doesn't apply into the profile grid. So far though, everything works as you describe that you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

i.stack.imgur.com/g9Eh6.png this is the height of `profile-grid` & not the `profile-card`. `255px is set on profile-card`..

You have to add `height:100%` on  `profile-grid`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: roboto;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.profile-card {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 255px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.301);
}

.profile-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 1fr;
}

.social-ava {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: opacity 0.15s;
}

.social-ava:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.social-text {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.social-name {
  margin-top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s;
}

.social-name:hover {
  color: rgb(52, 98, 167);
}

.mutual-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
  margin-top: 6px;
  align-items: center;
}

.mutual-pic {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mutual-friend {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mutual-friend:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.social-add {
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(25, 118, 240);
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.social-add:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!-- profile card start -->
<div class="profile-card">

  <!-- profile grid start -->
  <div class="profile-grid">

    <!-- row 1: picture start -->
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="social-ava"></div>
      <!-- placeholder for profile picture -->
    </div>
    <!-- row 1: picture end -->

    <!-- row 2: info start -->
    <div class="social-text">
      <p class="social-name"><strong>Name</strong></p>

      <div class="mutual-grid">
        <!-- grid for mutual friends info start -->
        <div class="mutual-pic"></div>
        <!-- placeholder for mutual's profile picture -->
        <p class="mutual-friend">2 mutual friends</p>
      </div>
      <!-- grid for mutual friends info end -->

      <button class="social-add">Add Friend</button>
    </div>
    <!-- row 2: info end -->

  </div>
  <!-- profile grid end -->

</div>
<!-- profile card end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out exactly what's wrong here, since the profile card actually seems to be `255px` in height, however, I'll assume you mean the `.profile-grid` itself:

Your problem here is that while the card element fills its space correctly, the grid doesn't. To do that, you have to make it so that it fills up its parent element completely. Simply:

```
.profile-grid{
    height:100%;
}
```

That alone seems to be solving your problem, but also consider that your `.social-text` div has some padding, which causes its contents to go outside the grid's row.

[image: social text exceeing the row's flow]

For that, you have to either make it smaller by 16 pixels or make the second row bigger by 16 pixels. Still no need to actually implement this though.

Final Code (only with the first implementations):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: roboto;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
}

.profile-card {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width:150px;
  height:255px;
  border:none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.301);
}

.profile-grid {
  display:grid;
  height:100%;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows:150px 1fr;
}

.social-ava {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: opacity 0.15s;
}

.social-ava:hover {
  opacity:0.8;
}

.social-text {
  height:100%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.social-name {
  margin-top:0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s;
}

.social-name:hover {
  color:rgb(52, 98, 167);
}

.mutual-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
  margin-top:6px;
  align-items: center;
}

.mutual-pic {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mutual-friend {
  font-size: 12px;
  color:rgb(80, 80, 80);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mutual-friend:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.social-add {
  margin-top:6px;
  padding:8px 16px;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(25, 118, 240);
  font-size:12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.social-add:hover {
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href"style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- profile card start -->
    <div class="profile-card"> 

      <!-- profile grid start -->
      <div class="profile-grid">
        
        <!-- row 1: picture start -->
        <div class="image-container"> 
          <div class="social-ava"></div> <!-- placeholder for profile picture -->
        </div> 
        <!-- row 1: picture end -->

        <!-- row 2: info start -->
        <div class="social-text"> 
          <p class="social-name"><strong>Name</strong></p>

          <div class="mutual-grid"> <!-- grid for mutual friends info start -->
              <div class="mutual-pic"></div> <!-- placeholder for mutual's profile picture -->
              <p class="mutual-friend">2 mutual friends</p>
          </div> <!-- grid for mutual friends info end -->

          <button class="social-add">Add Friend</button>
        </div> 
        <!-- row 2: info end -->
        
      </div>
      <!-- profile grid end -->

    </div>
    <!-- profile card end -->

  </body>

</html>
```